# Gmail always resend 2FAA text message when I use strict content blocking on firefox

Tags: firefox, gmail, cookies

I have added https://mail.google.com to the white list in the privacy settings, but it doesn't help it.

Isn't there a way to limit google cookies and also not having to receive a 2FAA text message each time?

Comment: stop using the gmail web interface, just have it forward all your email somewhere else.

Comment: I know, fastmail seems nice. Not my question though.